# What are those things on the B747 engine pylons?

Tags: feature-identification, engine-design, boeing-747, engine-pylon

I noticed some dots and lines on the Boeing 747 engine pylons. What are they?

[image]

The above image is as seen in this [video at 2:18](https://youtu.be/Ul7LE_oWdHw?t=138).

Comment: The linear objects are the strut aft fairing panel latches. The panels hinge along the dark horizontal line seen in your photo. There is an engine support strut beneath the panels. There are also hydraulic system components contained in that compartment.

Answer (score 5):

These are latches holding the engine support pylon panel in closed. Behind this panel is the diagonal brace.

This area was modified ~1992 due to the [El Al Flight 1862](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Al_Flight_1862) and [China Airlines Flight 358](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Airlines_Flight_358) crashes.

---

See [FAA Lessons Learned](https://archive.is/B1GhD#selection-24.0-33.15) (via archive.is).